# CRUD operation to insert data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

My program compiles with no errors but unfortunately it does not insert the data into the database. the database table is called "Customers"
Any help would be great here is my code
in my model i have:

```
public ActionResult Apply()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Default1/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Apply(CUSTOMER customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();
        try
        {
            db.CUSTOMERs.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Apply");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

then at my mvc i have:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GreenEnergyGr.Models.CUSTOMER>" %>
```

Apply

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

### Apply

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>CUSTOMER</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerSurname) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerSurname) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerSurname) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerAddress) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerAddress) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerAddress) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerLocation) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerLocation) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerLocation) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerTelephone) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerTelephone) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerTelephone) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerEmail) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerEmail) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEmail) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerPostCode) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPostCode) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerPostCode) %>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: do you know how to debug/trace? did you see code running through the `db.SaveChanges();` line?

Comment: The return View() line after you validate the model looks awfully sketchy. I suspect it's reaching that line of code and redisplaying your form and not even calling the code to add the item to the database. You should also add some more code to the try catch instead of just re-displaying the view.

Comment: how?that is my question!

Comment: Just take it out - you  already have a redirect after the call to db.SaveToChanges()

Answer (score 0):

If your view is valid then you have configured you probably did save data just not to the database you are looking at.  If you have not properly specified the name in the right place entity framework will extract a name.  Look at the other databases on the server and see if there is a rogue.

Comment: I im sure that i have linked it to the right source and connection string.